# Styling of list of EJS Template pages not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

I am busy with a website for logging calls. The calls can have different urgencies (Emergency, Urgent, ASAP). I am using a EJS template for the call content and I am displaying the calls on the page using a for loop in the calls ejs page. I attached a browser-side javascript file to the EJS template file to style the background of the template differently depending on what the urgency value is (red for emergency, orange for urgent, and so on). However when I run it only the first template body color is changed and the rest are all the default color. Can someone see what I am doing wrong? Or is there a better way to style according to value?

In the calls.ejs file:

```
    <% if (!calls || calls.length===0) { %>
        <p>No calls found!</p>
        <% } else { %>
            <ol id="posts-list">
                <% for (const call of calls) { %>
                    <li>
                        <%- include('includes/call-item', { call: call }) %>
                    </li>
                    <% } %>
            </ol>
            <% } %>
```

In the call-item.js:

```
<article class="post-item" id="main">
  <p class="post-item-author"><time datetime="<%= call.CallDate %>"><%= call.CallDate %></time>    </p>
  <p><span><%=call.CategoryName%></span><span id="urgency"><%=call.UrgencyName%></span><span>    <%=call.Status%></span><span><%=call.Email%></span></p>
  <p><span><%=call.Location%></span><span id="body"><%=call.Description%></span></p>
  <div class="post-actions">
    <p></p>

    <form action="calllog/<%= call.CallID %>/delete" method="post">
      <button class="btn btn-alt">Delete Call</button>
    </form>

    <a href="/calllog/<%= call.CallID %>/edit">Edit Call</a> 
    <a class="btn" href="/callactions/<%= call.CallID %>">Action Call</a>
  </div>
</article>

<script src="javascript/call-item.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

In the call-item.js:

```
const span = document.querySelector('#urgency');
const main = document.querySelector('#main');
const urgency = span.innerHTML;

main.className = '';

if (urgency === 'Emergency') {
    main.classList.add('post-item');
    main.classList.add('emergency');
} else if (urgency === 'Urgent') {
    main.classList.add('post-item');
    main.classList.add('urgent');
} else if (urgency === 'ASAP') {
    main.classList.add('post-item');
    main.classList.add('asap');
}
```

The CSS:

```
#posts-list {
    margin: 3rem auto;
    max-width: 50rem;
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  .post-item {
    margin: 1rem 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: rgb(220, 204, 252);
  }

  .emergency {
    background-color: rgb(255, 125, 125);
  }

  .urgent {
    background-color: rgb(250, 154, 28);
  }

  .asap {
    background-color: rgb(183, 250, 28);
  }
```